# URL Rewrite - Mod Rewrite with Arguments

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I used the following htaccess code to rewrite url to index.php

It works good with urls as:

http://www.site.com/sub1/
http://www.site.com/sub1/

but not when I add query string to the url like, it breaks:

http://www.site.com/sub1/?uid=7897
http://www.site.com/sub1/?uid=7897

How could I make the code with with query arguments also.

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.
RewriteRule ^.+/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Note that QSA is unnecessary unless you are adding query string parameters in the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QSA` flag should be enough to keep the query string alive.

So this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+/?$ index.php [QSA,L]
```